# Java syntax: switch case as variable?

Tags: java, syntax, switch-statement, case

In java this syntax is possible:

```
int a = 1;
int i = 0;
i = a == 1 ? 5 : 8;
```

So in this case i would be 5 because a = 1.

Is there a similar syntax for **switch case?**
For example like this:

```
int a = 1;
int i = 0;
i = switch (a) {
    case 1: 5; break;
    case 2: 8; break;
}
```

So that i would also be 5 because a = 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this syntax is not supported. But you could simulate such behavior with Java 8:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Switch {

    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T, U> Optional<U> of(T value, Case<T, U>... cases) {
        for (Case<T, U> c : cases) {
            if (value.equals(c.getTestValue())) {
                return Optional.of(c.getSupplier().get());
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public static <T, U> Case<T, U> when(T testValue, Supplier<U> supplier) {
        return new Case<T, U>() {
            public T getTestValue() {
                return testValue;
            }

            public Supplier<U> getSupplier() {
                return supplier;
            }
        };
    }

    public interface Case<T, U> {
        Supplier<U> getSupplier();

        T getTestValue();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
String s = Switch.of(1,
        when(0, () -> "zero"),
        when(1, () -> "one"),
        when(2, () -> "two"))
        .orElse("not found");
System.out.println(s);
```

Of course you can tweak the code to fit your needs.

Comment: Zoiks. Perhaps this solution is a bit on the heavyweight side to avoid a few `=` operators?

Comment: It depends. You can go much further, close to Scala's pattern matching, then it becomes really useful. I think `switch` "as it is" is just inconvenient and dangerous, and even my modest makeshift implementation avoids some of the problems (no "fall-through", the default case must be handled).

Comment: Preventing fall-through - maybe; handling of the default case is more easily enforced by definite assignment, though.

Comment: Again, it depends. `Optional` has several ways to deal with missing values, or you might even prefer to "stay" in `Optional` to deal with the problem later.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Only this is possible:

```
switch (a) {
    case 1: i = 5; break;
    case 2: i = 8; break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such syntax, but you can wrap your switch statement in a method and achieve similar behavior :

```
public int switchMethod (int a)
{
     switch (a) {
        case 1: return 5;
        case 2: return 8;
        default : return 0;
    }
}

...
int i = switchMethod (1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively used chained ternary statements:

```
int i = (a == 1) ? 5
      : (a == 2) ? 8
      : 0;
```